# sqlfetch table not found in channel regular expression

Tags: sql, r, ms-access, odbc, rstudio

I am trying to find fetch multiple Access files in which the table I need has a different name each time.

Example :

- in Access file 1, table name is "base1"
- in Access file 2, table name is "base2"
- etc.

I tried the following function which will be later used within a map function to fetch all Access files from my directory:

```
fetch <- function (x) { y <- odbcConnectAccess2007(x) sqlFetch(y,"^base.$") odbcCloseAll() }
```

R does not seem to like regular expressions on `sqlfetch` since I get the following message :

> Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable) : ‘^base.$’: table not found on channel

Please note that this works perfectly when I use "base1" as `sqltable` instead of "^base.$"

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem :

```
    fetch <- function (x) {
      y <- odbcConnectAccess2007(x)
      find_table_name <-
        str_extract(sqlTables(y)$TABLE_NAME, "^(base.*)$") %>%
        na.omit
      table_result <- sqlFetch(y, find_table_name[1])
      return(table_result)
      odbcCloseAll()

}
```